# What is the underlying Text-Rendering Engine of Internet Explorer?Is it the same as other Windows Apps(GDI)?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, winapi, gdi+

I want to know how Internet Explorer(or other Browser such as Chrome and Firefox running on Windows) displays the text content of a HTML. Does it ultimately call the TextOut(hdc,x,y,psText,iLength) Win32 GDI API Function as other windows applications do ? 
I failed to draw text with ClearType using GDI.So I wonder whether Internet Explorer using a different Text-Rendering Engine or not.

Comment: This question doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 uses [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for its text display; earlier versions used GDI functions.

Comment: I thougth the tick was more "this is the answer I accepted" It's still OT though :)

Comment: @Carey Gregory:EricLaw comes from Microsoft (look at his name) so he can't be wrong.